# Set excel formula to entire column relatively in Java?

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi

Is there any way to set excel formula to entire column relatively in Java ?

For example in excel column A and B contains numbers and column C contains addition formula A+B

I wanted to repeat same formula to entire C column like C1 = A1+B1,C2=A2+B2.

Currently I'm doing this by some dirty logic which is replacing Number (1,2 ..so on ) with row count. But in real cases formulas are very big and complex and difficult to replace with above tactic.

Is Apache POI providing anything to copy such formulas relatively like in excel ?

Comment: I've successfully solved this problem by using the [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function in its `R1C1` mode. In my formulas I write e.g. `INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]",0)` to access the cell left to the current cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Excel's best practice approach would be using `R1C1` references for this problem. With this references we could apply `=SUM(RC1:RC2)` to the range `C2:C10` for example. The `R` means this row while `C1` means column 1 (`A`) and `C2` means column 2 ( `B`).

Unfortunately does apache poi not support `R1C1` references. So the only approach I can see is using `CellReference` for this. A `CellReference` can get the [CellRefParts](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#getCellRefParts()) as the three parts of the cell reference, the Sheet name (or null if none supplied), the 1 based row number, and the A based column letter. So we can use this parts within the formulas.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class UsingCellReferenceInFormula {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    String[][] data = new String[][]{
                          {"Number1","Number2","Sum","Complex"},
                          {"123","456", null, null},
                          {"23.45","67.89", null, null},
                          {"123","-456", null, null},
                          {"-123.456","456.78", null, null}
                      };

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

    int r = 0;
    for(String[] dataRow : data){
        Row row = sheet.createRow(r++);
        int c = 0;
        for(String dataCell : dataRow){
            Cell cell = row.createCell(c++);
            if ( r == 1 ) cell.setCellValue(dataCell);
            else if ( c < 3 ) cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(dataCell));
            else if ( c == 3 ) {
                CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(cell);
                String thisR = cellReference.getCellRefParts()[1]; 
                cell.setCellFormula("SUM(A" + thisR + ":B" + thisR + ")");
            } else if ( c == 4 ) {
                CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(cell);
                String thisR = cellReference.getCellRefParts()[1]; 
                cell.setCellFormula("IF(AND(A" + thisR + ">0,B" + thisR + ">0),SUM(A" + thisR + ":B" + thisR + "),MAX(A" + thisR + ":B" + thisR + "))");
            }
        }
    }


    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("UsingCellReferenceInFormula.xlsx");
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your input. I'm looking into this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class UsingCellReferenceInFormula {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String[][] data = new String[][]{
                              {"Number1","Number2","Sum","Complex"},
                              {"123","456", null, null},
                              {"23.45","67.89", null, null},
                              {"123","-456", null, null},
                              {"-123.456","456.78", null, null}
                          };

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

        int r = 0;
        for(String[] dataRow : data){
            Row row = sheet.createRow(r++);
            int c = 0;
            for(String dataCell : dataRow){
                Cell cell = row.createCell(c++);
                if ( r == 1 ) cell.setCellValue(dataCell);
                else if ( c < 3 ) cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(dataCell));
                else if ( c == 3 ) {
                    CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(cell);
                    String thisR = cellReference.getCellRefParts()[1]; 
                    cell.setCellFormula("SUM(A" + thisR + ":B" + thisR + ")");
                } else if ( c == 4 ) {
                    CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(cell);
                    String thisR = cellReference.getCellRefParts()[1]; 
                    cell.setCellFormula("IF(AND(A" + thisR + ">0,B" + thisR + ">0),SUM(A" + thisR + ":B" + thisR + "),MAX(A" + thisR + ":B" + thisR + "))");
                }
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("UsingCellReferenceInFormula.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```